# Term for helpful information in a form

Tags: forms, terminology

I'm writing up a proposal and got stumped on the description for this element:

[image]

The informative text (in pink) underneath a field is there to provide a reason for the required data, therefore answering a users uncertainty around why they need to fill in this field.

The information behind the 'i' icon plainly says you must be x years old to register so this isn't duplicate information.

Is there a specific term for this type of element within a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Material design refers to this as 'helper text' for its position in the form.

From **[Material Design](https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#anatomy)**:

> Helper text conveys additional guidance about the input field, such as how it will be used. It should only take up a single line, being persistently visible or visible only on focus.

[image]

Your specific example is sort of microcopy-ish, as it's encouraging you to fill out the form (and the benefits of doing so), but not technically helping you understand *how* to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the catch-all term for this type of text would be 'microcopy', and usually they are classified or grouped based on the user interface element that they support.

So in this case I think you could call this an input field microcopy, or if you want to be even more specific then a date input field microcopy and people should have a good idea of what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's microcopy since there's many places where you'd include microcopy, including inside the information tooltip next to the input label.

I'd simply refer to that as "Input explanation text" or "Auxiliary input label". I think the second is preferred because the word "label" doesn't imply it's about text entered by the user.

In the end I don't think there's a standard name for that.